# How to best align href link left, and text explanation to the right

Tags: html, css

This seems simple to me, but after days of trying (I have very limited experience) and searching for a solution, I have drawn a blank.
 I am creating a page of links on a single html page with embedded css style for use in a browser window.

I wish to simply align my link to the left of my div, with a text explanation of the link which aligns to the right of the div.  There is a wrapper div which contains two of these other div's (right and left), which contain boxes (categories) of links.  The first example is merely using periods to create the desired space.

So far I have tried the below HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="div_body_side1">
            <div id="div_category01">
                <p>
                    <A HREF="http://www.webaddress" > Short Description
                    </A>.................... Longer description of where this link will take you
            </p>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also thought I may try this method (below) but I don't know how to color the text in the long description and align it to the far right of the category div.

```
 <tr>
 <td>
 <A HREF="http://www.webaddress" > Short Description</A>
 </td>
 <td>
  Longer description of where this link will take you
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Will I have to create two more side-by-side divs inside each category to achieve what I'd like?
I will also need the divs and text to 'shrink' (scale) horizontally for small laptop use and I know that a lot of div's (floating) somehow prevents proper scaling.

I apologise for my lack of expertise, but I really have been looking for a solution for days.
 Thank-you in advance for any assistance.
.............
..................................................

Hello again.
 Unfortunately, Billy Chan's answer did not work (but thank you for reminding me to use the 'title' attribute).  I have tried it with a list of three links and what happens is the output looks like this:

link1link2link3      explanation1explanation2explanation3

Here is what I used:

```
<div>
    <span class="link">
    <a href="#whatever">Whatever</a></span>
    <span class="explanation">Whatever explain</span>

    <span class="link">
    <a href="https://www.google.com.au"title="Google">Google search</a>
    </span>
    <span class="explanation">Secure Google search page
    </span>

    <span class="link">
    <a href="http://www.google.com/ncr" >Google search</A>
    </span>
    <span class="explanation">US Google search page
    </span>

</div>
```

...with the following CSS:

```
<style>
    .link, .explanation {display:inline}
    .link {float: left}
    .explanation {float: right}
</style>
```

I shall now try the other solutions that have been kindly provided.
Thank-you all so much.

.......................................

Thank-you dbaseman, but your solution requires two more divs within my category divs, does it not?  I can't apply your "div class="right"" to my Category divs (which are an IDs), can I?

Will now try Urg mu's solution.   Cheers.

Oh.. Urg mu - it seems you have provided a solution for colouring the text only.  Your solution isn't going to align my 'long explanation' to the right is it?

On to Naveen Sharma.  I'm sorry but can you please explain what your solution is actually supposed to do?

Thank you all again.  I am learning a lot.
Cheers.

Please see this horrible jsFiddle version of what I am trying to achieve.  Yes, it includes lots of testing things and also the 'solutions' provided here.., and you will have to drag your browser window to the far right and the 'result' window to the far left to see my two divs side-by-side:

http://jsfiddle.net/wreckanoid/CdN2z/

Comment: how should it be displayed ?

Answer (score 2):

Direct answer:

Use two spans to wrap links and explanation. Example

```
<div id="catgory01">
  <span class="link"><a href="#whatever">Whatever</a></span>
  <span class="explanation">Whatever explain</span>
</div>
```

Then define style of the two spans

```
<style>
  .link, .explanation {display:inline}
  .link {float: left}
  .explanation {float: right}
</style>
```

The reason to wrap the link is you may not want all your links behave like this.

This answer should work, but you may find problem is your link anchor or explanation is too long, they may overlap. Just pay attention to that.

A further answer: The correct way to explain a link is to use title attribute

```
<a href="#whatever" title="Explanation">Whatever</a>
```

This way when you hover the link, you get the hint.

Comment: Unfortunately, Billy Chan's answer did not work (but thank you for reminding me to use the 'title' attribute).  I have tried it with a list of three links and what happens is the output looks like this:


link1link2link3         explanation1explanation2explanation3


 Please see this horrible jsFiddle version of what I am trying to achieve.  Yes, it includes lots of testing things and also the 'solutions' provided here.., and you will have to drag your browser window to the far right and the 'result' window to the far left to see my two divs side-by-side:

http://jsfiddle.net/wreckanoid/CdN2z/

Comment: I saw your code. It's inappropriate to wrap the line by p tag because paragraph will stop when no more characters to show. My suggestion: 1. Use table instead of div for each block, it's nothing wrong when using table in right case. 2. Forget the dots after links at present, it makes things complicated. Once you get all layouts and text right, you can test adding dots by something like content after.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
div {  width:400px; border:red 1px solid; padding:10px 0px; }
p {  overflow:auto; margin:0px;
    background:url('http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/MathematicaCharacters/Ellipsis.gif') 100% repeat-x ;
}
a {
    float:left; padding:0px 5px 0px 10px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.desc {
    float:right; padding:0px 10px 0px 5px;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#333;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <p>
    <a href="#link" >IAClient</A>
    <span class="desc">QUT Internet Access Client</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#link" >AARNet</A>
    <span class="desc">AARNet's FTP & HTTP Mirror</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CZt8R/

Comment: Urg mu - it seems you have provided a solution for colouring the text only. Your solution isn't going to align my 'long explanation' to the right is it?

Comment: opps.. sorry. I saw your updated code and thought of something that might help you. :) this time its complete. Please refer to my updated answer

Comment: Look into the ellipsis generated by the P's background. Using this code, allows you to forget adding dots, worse counting how many fits.

Comment: Hello, Ung Mu. 
 Your solution looks very promising!  I would love to know how you are finding the 'elipsis.gif' on the Wolfram site.  I have had a look and can't see how you do it.  I would like to try an underscore ( _ ) instead but I can't find how to search for or create it.  Can you help?  Thank-you.

Comment: pretty easy. You can actually draw an image using MSpaint, photoshop or whatever.. save the file and upload to make it available online. I just googled elipsis image (since its available) and used it as background. _Hit upvote if you find my answer useful, also select as best answer if you're truley satisfied :)_ Cheers, glad to help.
You caln also try..  http://galeon.sourceforge.net/TWiki/TWikiDocGraphics

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use `float: left` and `float: right` on the link and the description, respectively.

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.webaddress" > Short Description </a>
<div class="right">.................... Longer description of where this link will take you</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }​
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/r2uqV/1)

---

**Edit post update**

Two keys to getting this kind of layout:

- Use fixed (percentage-based) left-margins for the links, and for the descriptions
- Display a long string of ellipses "..............." and use `overflow-x: hidden` to hide the excess

[Another demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/agmYW/1/)

Comment: Thank-you dbaseman, but your solution requires two more divs within my category divs, does it not?  I can't apply your "div class="right"" to my Category divs (which are an IDs), can I?

Comment: Please see this horrible jsFiddle version of what I am trying to achieve.  Yes, it includes lots of testing things and also the 'solutions' provided here.., and you will have to drag your browser window to the far right and the 'result' window to the far left to see my two divs side-by-side:

http://jsfiddle.net/wreckanoid/CdN2z/

Comment: @user1828542 did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Hello, dbaseman.  I'm really trying hard to get things working.  Your solution looks good, but I can't get it right just yet.  You may not hear from me for a couple of days, but rest-assured, I'll let you know.  Thank-you.

Comment: @user1828542 thanks, I'd be curious to see how it turns out.  See my update above and Fiddle, in case it helps at all:  http://jsfiddle.net/agmYW/1/

Answer (score 0):

In The HTML that you have given add folowing line of code

```
<style>
.div_body_side1 p a{width:200px;float:left}
</style>
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenksh/u3Hjk/)

Comment: Naveen Sharma. I'm sorry but can you please explain what your solution is actually supposed to do?

Comment: Here I am giving float:left and width:100 to 
<a href="#whatever">Whatever</a> so that it will be at equal distance from descrition.. Check example
http://jsfiddle.net/naveenksh/u3Hjk/1/

Comment: I have updated your shared jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/naveenksh/CdN2z/7/   .......
Here I enclosed set with dl tag ... and then added following css
#div_category01 dt{width:80px;float:left}
#div_category01 dd{margin-left:90px}
#div_category01 dl{overflow:auto}
dt{    margin-left: 0;    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have settled on.
  I may add some underscores between the links and the explanations, but I think I now have the basis for a great, embedded CSS link menu page for browser use.
 Here is the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/wreckanoid/zV9Sd/embedded/result/

Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/wreckanoid/zV9Sd/

```
.wrapper
{
position:relative;
background-color: #e7ecfa;
width: 90%; 
margin-left:15%;
margin-right:15%;
height:auto;
display: block; 
overflow:auto; 
border:inset .5em #ccffff;
margin: 1em auto;
box-shadow: 0 0.3em 1em #000000;    
}

.div_body_side1
{
float: LEFT;
position:relative;
text-align: left;
/*  border: solid 1px #d1d7e5; */ 
width: 45%;
display: block; 
margin-left: 2.5em;
margin-right: 1em;
margin-top: 2em;
margin-bottom: 2em;
padding: .5em;
white-space:normal;
clear:none;
}


.div_body_side2
{   
clear:none;
float:left;
position:reative;
text-align: left;
/*  border: solid 1px #d1d7e5;  */ 
width: 45%;
display:inline;
margin-right: 1em;
margin-top: 2em;
margin-bottom: 2em;
padding: .5em;
}   

#div_category01, #div_category02, #div_category03, #div_category04,     #div_category05, #div_category06, #div_category07, #div_category08, #div_category09
{
background-color: #eff5fb;
margin: 1em 1em;
width: auto;
display: block;
border:ridge 6px #ff3333;
box-shadow: 0 0.3em 1em #000000;
position:relative;
clear:both;
}


.center
{
text-align: center;
}

.right 
{
float: right;
padding-right: 20px;
color: #cc6600;
}

body 
{ 
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

h1
{
text-align: center;
}

h2 
{
text-align: center;
}

img.center
{   
display: block;   
margin: 0 auto;
}

a 
{ 
color: blue;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<H1> Test Bookmarks Menu</H1>

<a href="http://www.qut.edu.au" >
<IMG SRC="http://www.tils.qut.edu.au/graphics/logo.gif"
BORDER="4" title="QUT logo" alt="QUT logo" class="center" /></a>



    <div class="div_body_side1">

        <div id="div_category01">

    <H2>CATEGORY 1 HEADER</H2>
    <br>

    <a href="https://www.google.com.au/" > Google Australia
    </a>

    <span class="right">
        Google Secure, Australia
    </span><br><br>

    <a href="https://www.google.com/ncr" > Google USA
    </a>

    <span class="right">    
        Google Secure, USA
    </span><br><br>

    <a href="https://encrypted.google.com/" > Google Encrypted
    </a>

    <span class="right">    
        Google Secure, Encrypted
    </span><br><br>

    <a href="https://www.google.com.au/" > Google Australia
    </a>

    <span class="right">
        Google Secure, Australia
    </span><br><br>     


    </div><!-- close category01 -->



</div><!-- close div_body_side1 -->



<div class="div_body_side2">

    <div id="div_category05">

    <H2>Category 5 Header </H2>

        <a href="https://www.google.com.au/" > Google Australia
        </a>

    <span class="right">            
        Google Secure, Australia
    </span><br><br>

        <a href="https://www.google.com/ncr" > Google USA
        </a>

    <span class="right">            
        Google Secure, USA
    </span><br><br>     

        <a href="https://encrypted.google.com/" > Google Encrypted
        </a>

    <span class="right">            
        Google Secure, Encrypted
    </span><br><br>

        <a href="https://www.google.com.au/" > Google Australia 
        </a>

    <span class="right">            
        Google Secure, Australia
    </span><br><br>


    </div><!-- close category05 -->



</div><!-- close div_body_side2 -->
```

Thanks to all you people I feel I'm now getting a grip on this CSS stuff.. !  :-)

I will be adding the 'title' tag to all the links, too.
Cheers.